# Generating a reasonable ctags database for Boost

Tags: c++, linux, vim, boost, ctags

I'm running Ubuntu 8.04 and I ran the command:

```
$ ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f ~/.vim/tags/stdlibcpp /usr/include/c++/4.2.4/
```

to generate a ctags database for the standard C++ library and STL ( libstdc++ ) on my system for use with the [OmniCppComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520) vim script.  This gave me a very reasonable 4MB tags file which seems to work fairly well.

However, when I ran the same command against the installed Boost headers:

```
$ ctags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f ~/.vim/tags/boost /usr/include/boost/
```

I ended up with **a 1.4 GB tags file!**  I haven't tried it yet, but that seems likes it's going to be too large to be useful.  Is there a way to get a slimmer, more usable tags file for my installed Boost headers?

**Edit**

Just as a note, libstdc++ includes TR1, which has allot of Boost libs in it.  So there must be something weird going on for libstdc++ to come out with a 4 MB tags file and Boost to end up with a 1.4 GB tags file.

Just ran across this on the Boost mailing list:

[Boost-users Boost and autocompletion](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2009/09/51448.php)

**THE ANSWER**

Thanks to Neg_EV for figuring out what the problem was, but there's a much better way of solving the problem than what he suggested:

Make sure apt-file is install, and run the following commands

( I keep my library tags in ~/.vim/tags/ ):

```
$ sudo apt-file update
$ apt-file list boost | grep -E -o '/usr/include/.*\.(h|hpp)' | grep -v '/usr/include/boost/typeof/' > ~/.vim/tags/boost-filelist
$ ctags --sort=foldcase --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f ~/.vim/tags/boost -L ~/.vim/tags/boost-filelist
```

I've upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 and Boost 1.40 and that's what I tested this solution on, but it should work with any Boost version as far as I can tell.

Comment: could something similar be done without using apt-file (to make it more widely useful?) e.g. just using --exclude on the ctags command line?

Comment: Just like you I started at over 1.4 G.  Removed the typeof but I'm still at 391 M.  I'd like to slim it down to possibly a tenth of that.  On boost 1.52... Any suggestions?

Comment: @drfrogsplat not sure this is still relevant for you, but I achieved the same effect without resorting to package manager utilities using zsh: `ctags -R /usr/include/boost/*~*typeof(/)` (other cmdargs to ctags ommitted). You need to have extended globbing enabled for this to work.

Comment: @zanegray the other offenders can be found with a count for the path of the directory under `/usr/include/boost/<libname>`. Something like this worked for me: `grep -o '/usr/include/boost/[^/]*/' /path/to/boost-tags-file | sort | uniq --count` (this will take a while). `phoenix` and `spirit` were also pretty big besides `typeof`, but you might be able to exclude even more depending on what libraries you don't care about (or don't need ctags for).

Comment: With Boost 1.55, `fusion` was also a heavy one (1.4GB for `typeof`, 193MB for `phoenix` and 122MB for `fusion`). The rest is less than 6MB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know this post is a little old, but I just ran into the same problem.  I looked into it a little further and it seems it is one folder in boost that is causing the problem: ***typeof***.  I am using boost 1.37 and my tags file was 1.5G, typeof was 1.4G of that.  So I just created a tags file without that directory included and the resulting size was 70M.  I was even able to sort it without running out of space :)  I imagine in newer versions of boost they may be other projects that are too large however the general solution I found is this...

1. Generate a tag file for each boost folder seperately, a simple bash for loop should be able to do this.
2. Look at which ones are too large.
3. Either create a new single tags file excluding those large directories or keep the tag files separated simply deleting the ones that are too large.

This is the script I used (taken from comments):

```
for i in $(find -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep -v '^\.$' | sed 's/\.\///' ); do
    echo $i;
    ctags -f ~/tmp_tags/$i.tags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --languages=c++ --sort=foldcase $i;
done
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't suppose you could post the script?

Comment: This should generate separate tag files to find the culprit:

for i in $(find -maxdepth 1 -type d | grep -v '^\.$' | sed 's/\.\///' ); do echo $i; ctags -f ~/tmp_tags/$i.tags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --languages=c++ --sort=foldcase $i; done

Then to generate a single tags file you can simply do something similar to:
ctags -f ~/tmp_tags/all.tags -R --c++-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q --languages=c++ --sort=foldcase $(ls -d * | grep -v typeof );

The grep -v part is where I exclude things such as typeof.  Both commands assume you are in the boost include dir.

Comment: Finally got around to trying out your answer.  Your idea works wonderfully, but I have a much easier way to implement it.  See the edit to my OP for details.

Answer (score 8):

use the option

```
--sort=foldcase
```

With this the searching of the tags becomes faster.

Quoting from the [man page of ctags](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ctags) : 
"The foldcase value specifies case insensitive (or case-folded) sorting. Fast binary searches of tag files sorted with case-folding will require special support from tools using tag files, such as that found in the ctags readtags library, or Vim version 6.2 or higher (using "set ignorecase"). This option must appear before the first file name"

Comment: Will this reduce the size of the tags file to reasonable dimensions?  I mean, stdlibc++ includes the STL and TR1 which actually has allot of Boost in it - and it's only 4MB!

Comment: I am not sure about the size, but my tag search speed in VIM was increased atleast 5 fold..

Comment: No. Including the sort option gives me no gain in Ubuntu 10.04. Still getting the 1.4G file size

Comment: @ancechu:  There's a tested solution that works if you're interested see the OP.

Comment: even same size ctags with this option, but E341 error is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You SHOULD add this option to your ctags invocation:

```
    -I "BOOST_SYMBOL_VISIBLE BOOST_SYMBOL_IMPORT BOOST_SYMBOL_EXPORT BOOST_FORCEINLINE BOOST_CONSTEXPR=constexpr BOOST_CONSTEXPR_OR_CONST=constexpr BOOST_STATIC_CONSTEXPR=static\ constexpr BOOST_STD_EXTENSION_NAMESPACE=std BOOST_MOVABLE_BUT_NOT_COPYABLE+ BOOST_COPYABLE_AND_MOVABLE+ BOOST_COPYABLE_AND_MOVABLE_ALT+ BOOST_NOEXCEPT=noexcept BOOST_NOEXCEPT_OR_NOTHROW=noexcept BOOST_NOEXCEPT_IF+ BOOST_NOEXCEPT_EXPR+ BOOST_STATIC_CONSTANT BOOST_DELETED_FUNCTION BOOST_DEFAULTED_FUNCTION BOOST_NESTED_TEMPLATE BOOST_UNREACHABLE_RETURN+ BOOST_DEDUCED_TYPENAME=typename BOOST_CTOR_TYPENAME=typename BOOST_LIKELY+ BOOST_UNLIKELY+ BOOST_ALIGNMENT+ BOOST_FALLTHROUGH"
```

This is what I use for the ENTIRE /usr/include/boost subdirectory for Boost 1.55.  I get a tags file that is ~128MB.  **The -I seems to be the key here** and helps filter out spurious tag generation.

NOTE: I'm using ctags 5.9 on Ubuntu 14.04.  I have a special -I for generating ctags for C++ standard headers.  This took a while for me to figure out why some header files generated almost no tags while others generated enormous amounts of tags.

Answer (score -1):

beacuse the methods generatored(eg. vector50.hpp vector100.hpp ...) is too much so that ctags generator a large tags file

1. find /usr/include ( -name "*.h" -o -name "*.hpp" ) boost/typeof > boost_files.txt
2. edit boost_files.txt and remove vector50.hpp vector100.hpp vector150.hpp vector200.hpp
3. ctags --c++-kinds=+px --fields=+iaS --extra=+q -f test.tags -L boost_files.txt